# Npm publish to private scope keeps failing

Tags: npm, package, publish, organization, npm-publish

I've recently created a new Organization and went for the paid plan to publish unlimited private packages.

However, each time I try to publish my package to my Org, it keeps giving me the following error:

```
npm ERR! publish Failed PUT 403
npm ERR! code E403
npm ERR! Forbidden : @myScopeName/myPackageName
```

I've already logged out and then logged in as a scope; like this:

```
npm login scope=myScopeName
```

Which then returns the following

`logged in as myUserName to scope @myScopeName on http://registry.npmjs.org/`

And I've checked my `.npmrc` file and I have the following lines:

```
registry=http://registry.npmjs.org/
scope=myScopeName
@myScopeName:registry=http://registry.npmjs.org
```

Yet I still can't publish my package. Does anyone know if I've forgotten something else or if I did something wrong according to the above?

Thank you!

Comment: I see that you opened a report at [the official npm forums](https://npm.community/t/npm-publish-to-private-scope-keeps-failing/6274/2), could you convert this into a bug report?

Comment: Make sure you are logged in to the correct user: `npm login` and follow instructions. Then try to publish again. if that doesn't help, create a `.npmrc` file and [create a token](https://docs.npmjs.com/creating-and-viewing-authentication-tokens) in the npm website and apply it to that local file. (place it on *gitignore*/*npmignore*)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is an error that can have many origins. I will list some of the possibilities below:

1. Your email address is not validated.
2. The package is assigned to a group, in which you are not present.
3. The name of the package you provided is similar to a yet existing package name in your scope.
4. A typo in the scope name.
5. A malformed package name.
6. ...

Through experimenting, I actually found out that the naming scheme for private npm packages is different than the one [officially documented](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json). It appears that privately pushed packages cannot contain underscores, and probably other stuff is also conflicting with the official documents.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I changed an underscore inside my package name to a dash and then the publishing worked. Weirdly enough, according to their [package.json documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json), this shouldn't have been a problem.

Comment: in my case, email address was not verified. Once I verified, npm publish started working

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I had an unverified email address associated with the account. After verifying the account, I was able to publish the package. Check the name of the package if it is conflicting with another package with a similar name. That might be an issue.