# Publishing scoped package fails with 403

Tags: npm, http-status-code-403, npm-publish

I'm the proud creator of [frs-replace](https://www.npmjs.com/package/frs-replace) package. After some discussions here and there, I've made the decision to move the package under new organisation's scope (`frsource`).

So, I've created [the organization](https://www.npmjs.com/org/frsource), and my [private npm account](https://www.npmjs.com/~frsgit) is marked as its owner. Then, I've changed the name of the package to `@frsource/frs-replace` and bumped the package's version. The problem is that when trying to publish the package with `npm publish --access=public` I always get the error:

```
18 http fetch PUT 403 https://registry.npmjs.org/@frsource%2freplace 1231ms
19 verbose stack Error: 403 Forbidden - PUT https://registry.npmjs.org/@frsource%2freplace - Forbidden
```

While publishing the [old package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/frs-replace) (linked with the same private account) everything works perfectly fine, so it's not anything connected with login I guess, right? Any ideas what's the problem here?

Comment: Related - https://stackoverflow.com/q/55241605/104380

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got my question answered on [npm CLI github](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/1012#issuecomment-629546298). Long story short: inside my organisation, I've created a team for the package, but I forgot to add myself to this team ‍♂️
After inviting myself to this team, I was finally able to publish my package under organisation scope!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and i solved it changing the scope name.
Looks like someone has already registered your organization name on npm.

Comment: Hm, that's interesting. But when I go for https://www.npmjs.com/org/frsource my organization is showing. Is there a possibility that someone pushed the scoped package without having organization in npm in the first place?